# Reg query/Reg delete key with embedded & failure

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am attempting to perform a registry query as per the following in a Win XP reg v3.0 via batch file environment:

```
reg query /v HKLM\SOFTWARE\DSAC\usb\vid_08ec&pid_204c
```

I am receiving argument errors truncating at the `&`. If I escape `^&`, the query parses the full key but fails to locate the registry key because, I believe, the search key is then `vid_08ec^&pid_204c`.

Can anyone advise how I can achieve this reg query and deletion against the `vid_08ec&pid_204c` string?

Answer (score 4):

Try like this :

```dos
reg query /v "HKLM\SOFTWARE\DSAC\usb\vid_08ec&pid_204c"
```

Comment: thanks sachadee this resolves the query but does not resolve the deletion

Comment: @feeks, this answers your question about the problem you had escaping & on the command lin

Comment: This resolves the issue of registry keys containing ampersands both for the reg delete. I did have to do some further research regarding piping the query to find here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185197/how-to-redirect-batch-reg-query-output-with-findstr) by @Endoro